# Building a json tree structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I will be passing a json string to a servlet via an ajax request :

```
function add() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "pathToServlet" ,
    dataType: "text",
    data: ({
        name : 'myJsonString'
    }),
    success: function(data) {
            alert('returned!!');
    });
}
```

To build up this json string I have a listener which when fired appends a new piece of json to string :

```
var json = "";
json += "{ new json ..... }"
```

Is this the correct way to build up the jSon String ? Should I be using jQuery methods to create a json object(if they exist) and add elements to it and then convert the json object to a string instead of creating the json string myself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would recommend doing is building up an *object*, and then when you're ready to send it to the server, serialize the object via `JSON.stringify`.

So for instance, you might have an object called `data`:

```
var data = {};
```

...to which you might periodically add properties:

```
data.foo = "bar";
data.stuff = {nifty: "stuff"};
```

Or perhaps `data` is an array:

```
var data = [];
```

...to which you add things:

```
data.push({nifty: "stuff"});
```

Then, when you're ready to send it:

```
function add() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "<%=savePortlet%>" ,
    dataType: "text",
    data: {
        name : JSON.stringify(data)
    },
    success: function(data) {
            alert('returned!!');
    });
}
```

Because you're passing an object into `ajax`, you don't have to worry about URL-encoding the JSON string; jQuery will do it for you.

`JSON.stringify` is defined as part of ECMAScript5 and suppoted natively by many browsers, but of course many of us have to support outdated versions of browsers. In those cases, you can get a "JSON shim" to add `JSON.stringify` to an environment that doesn't have it. One of those is available from the originator of JSON, Douglas Crockford, on [his github page](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/).

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery you can use [jquery-json](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/), a really handy plugin to handle JSON with JavaScript and jQuery.

Usage:

```
var jsonString = $.toJSON(myObject);
```